# How to execute proceduce to select sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008

I have a procedure A

When executing A 'dd/mm/yy'

I get the following results :

```
Nmonth  Origincode                        Rev       NYEAR
----------------------------------------------------------
03(MAR) OL Booking online               11024127    2016
03(MAR) OT Bookings from Other source   23728136    2016
03(MAR) RES Bookings from               5761904     2016
03(MAR) UK UK                           831169      2016
03(MAR) WS Bookings                     0           2016
```

I wasn't trying to select SQL but is not

```
select * 
from (exec A '1/1/2016') as results 
where coll = xyz
```

This is incorrect.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the query result from a stored procedure?

Comment: You need to save the procedure output to temp table and then select from that table with your WHERE condition.

Comment: You've tagged this for both Oracle and SQL Server.  Which of the two are you actually using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for result in sql server then:
You can put your stored procedure results into any temp table like:

//create your temp table

```
Create table #mytable
(
<your column list>
)
```

//insert data into temp table

```
insert into #mytable exec A '1/1/2016'
```

//select data with your filter or you can also put the where clause in stored procedure itself

```
Select * from #mytable where coll=xyz
```

or you can also insert data into temp table like :

```
SELECT  * 
INTO    #mytable FROM    
OPENQUERY(yourservername, 'exec A ''1/1/2016''')
```